# htaccess rewrite rule for backend/frontend app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a yii app that has separate back end and front end. I am trying to make friendly url.
I have tried some online tools but could not get it correct
So I want this url

- `http://mydomain.lc/abs/admin/some/crazy/urls` `(for example
  some/crazy/urls can be admin/index)`

will be rewritten to:

- `http://mydomain.lc/abs/backend.php/some/crazy/urls` `(because this
  url works directly)`

And I have also front end site but they are both in the same project so they share .httacess.
the rule for .htaccess for front end is:
this url:

- `http://mydomain.lc/abs/some/crazy/urls`   `(some can not be admin
  here, so we can differentiate btw fron and back end)`

should be

- `http://mydomain.lc/abs/index.php/some/crazy/urls`

I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^abs/admin/?(.*?)$ abs/backend.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?!abs/admin\/)(.*?)$ abs/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

the above script is not working.
Root is under abs folder and .htaccess in the root

Comment: Which one is not working? The first or the second RewriteRule? Or even both?

Comment: Root should be `http://mydomain.lc/` not `http://mydomain.lc/abs/` as you say. Please explain and confirm where is the .htaccess file.

Comment: root is here: `http://mydomain.lc/abs/`, because I do not owe the place that I put it, so project is located(beginning spot index.php) under abs and .htaccess is there, but NOT directly in http:// mydomain.lc / thanks

Comment: @OlafDietsche Both :(. but If I put the porject directly under mydomain.lc and remove all abs from rules it works as a charm. But I have abs in production server :(

Comment: In your rules the substitution URL would be `backend.php?url=/some/crazy/urls`, for example, but in your examples you have `backend.php/some/crazy/urls`. So, which one is it?

Comment: this one is correct: `backend.php/some/crazy/urls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to change anything except `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /abs`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /abs

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*?)$ backend.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!admin\/)(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the `RewriteBase`.

You may try this in the .htaccess file in `/abs` directory:

**Update** according to last OP comment: `this one is correct: backend.php/some/crazy/urls`

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abs

# Backend admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !backend\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)  /backend.php/$1   [QSA,L,NC]

# Frontend
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php      [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin           [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)     /index.php/$1   [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for contribution. can we correct this rule to rewrite for this: backend.php/some/crazy/urls instead of admin/backend.php?url=  thanks a ton man.

Comment: NOTE before backend.php there should not be admin in rewritten url, in `RewriteRule ^admin(.*)  admin/backend.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]` the should be backend.php/admin, No? I do not know regexes, but ultimately rewritten one should be `http://mydomain.lc/abs/backend.php/some/crazy/urls`

Comment: You are right. Remove the `admin/` part. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Modified. Please give it a try.